# Conversion (markdown --> pdf) of \"{e} fails with pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I need to put some french e's with a double point above into my text. The LaTeX markup I employ is `\"{e}` and I use that code in my markdown source, but Pandoc converts this to `"{e}` in the pdf and `"\{e\}` in a `.tex` file.

On the other hand, `\c{c}` for a cédille works fine, so I suppose this has to do with the way pandoc treats "-signs.

Is there a way to make the conversion work or do I have to first convert to TeX, than edit the tex-file by hand and compile it to pdf?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't need any latex code for accented letters for more than 20 years! Just use `utf8` input encoding and directly type `é, è à, ù`, &c.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the hint to utf8. Actually, I do use utf8, but until now I lacked the key combinations to enter the special signs in my editor -- your answer made me research how to do it, so now the problem is solved. I use vim, and just learned about the digraph feature to produce the signs directly - rendering with pandoc (pdflatex) works just fine.